# Automatic screen brightness adjuster

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, display

I'm sure there would be some freeware out there that does this, but for all my research I've failed to find anything!

So what I want: a piece of software that uses the webcam to automatically adjust the screen brightness **of my monitor** (not my laptop's screen).  I would like it to have some customization abilities so I can specify how frequently I want it to check the light and change screen brightness (rather than constantly being on).  I would also *like* a smooth transition when changing the brightness, but this is a nice feature, not a strictly necessary one!  This software **must** be free (I don't care if it's open source or just shareware)!

Answer (score 1):

[SoftonEyes (SoftPedia)](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/SoftonEyes.shtml) seems to work pretty well.
Not very feature rich but it does change the brightness based on the light picked up from the webcam.

Comment: Do not use this program! Avira detected a virus.

Comment: @GrayAdams: Do you have a link to a screenshot? All antiviruses here do not find any virus in it: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/fee513a8bf0491444592b4ab542fc9c5ffc86156aea46e09a4b03aa88ffbb3b0/analysis/

Comment: It doesn't use the native display brightness (on laptops). Instead it manually changes color balance.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program that automatically changes monitor brightness (not colour temperature) based on the time of sunset and sunrise:

It is available here: https://github.com/jacob-pro/solar-screen-brightness

It works for both external displays (DDC/CI) and laptop screens, on Windows & Linux.

Answer (score -2):

f.lux does this: it makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.

You can download it [here](https://justgetflux.com/)

Comment: I've used f.lux, it doesn't change the brightness of the screen and surely not using a webcam, it depends upon the local time + timezone and adds yellow color to the screen which is subtle to users eyes