# Calise (camera light sensor and adjuster) for Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, automation, display, webcam

[Calise](http://calise.sourceforge.net/wordpress/) detects background light through your webcam and adjusts your screens brightness. Unfortunately, it's linux only. Are there Windows friendly alternatives, or a way of emulating it while using windows?

Comment: Why do you want to run Windows?  :)

Comment: oh you! I could learn you the ways of the nexus mods if you have the spirit heathen...

Comment: I tried Google searches for `[ windows automatic screen brightness ]` and `[ windows automatic screen brightness webcam ]`.

Comment: Many modern laptops include a built-in dedicated light sensor. If yours does, and if you're running Windows 7 **Professional** or higher, you can enable a Windows feature called "Adaptive Brightness" which will do what you want.

Comment: Otherwise, click [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10165/automatic-screen-brightness-adjuster) and download "SoftonEyes", or click [here](http://superuser.com/questions/86725/software-to-auto-adjust-brightness-of-screens-from-webcam) and get set up with some other software which can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is definitely possible.  The best solution is to use your laptop's built-in light sensor, if it has one and you can use it.  See my comments on your question, above.